# Powershell - scriptblock global variable

Tags: powershell, jobs

In powershell, Im trying to update the global variable from within the script block it doesnt seem to work, it always prints out the initial value

```
$globalVariable = "Initial Value"

# Start a background job with a script block
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $Global:globalVariable  = "New Value"
}

Wait-Job $job
$jobResult = Receive-Job $job
Write-Host "Global Variable Value: $Global:globalVariable "
Remove-Job $job
```

Comment: Why not just consume the value as output from the job? Is it important that the job can communicate with you in realtime?

Comment: possible to show an example of this,

Comment: Show an example of why it might be important? You're the one asking the question, you tell me :)

Comment: this is not possible with `Start-Job`. also there is no reason to do it as Mathias states.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access external variables with `Start-Job`.
The only workaround that I know is using [Environment Variables ($env:*)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2)

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', 'OldVar', 'User')
Write-Host "Global Variable Value BEFORE: $([System.Environment]::getEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable','User')) "


$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', 'NewVar', 'User')
        
} 
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
Remove-Job $job

Write-Host "Global Variable Value AFTER: $([System.Environment]::getEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable','User')) "

# Necessary manual removal
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', $null, 'User')
```

Comment: tried this it's still the same, i get the same results

Comment: I updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: Awesome that works, is this the only way to tackle this

Answer (score 2):

`Start-Job` creates an external process to invoke the scriptblock and this external process has no access to the session state of its caller, updating a variable in the caller's scope from within a normal job is **not possible** (unless you consider an environmental variable an option, should be also understood that you're limited to only strings using this option).

In most cases you can do what [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) states, reassign the variable consuming the value as output from the job:

```bash
$variable = 'Initial Value'

# Start a background job with a script block
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    'New Value'
}

$variable = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
Write-Host "Variable Value: '$variable'"
```

If you really need to update caller's variables then you need to look into [ThreadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.4) or use a [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0). However, **do note both examples below are not thread safe operations, thread safety must be handled when updating reference types from mutliple threads.**

```bash
# With ThreadJob
$variable = 'Initial Value'
$psvar = Get-Variable variable

$job = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
    ($using:psvar).Value = 'Hello'
}
Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
Write-Host "Variable Value: '$variable'" # Variable Value: 'Hello'

# With a Runspace
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
    param($psvar)

    $psvar.Value = 'World'
}).AddParameter('psvar', $psvar)
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.Open()
$ps.Runspace = $rs
$task = $ps.BeginInvoke()
Write-Host "Variable Value: '$variable'" # Variable Value: 'World'
$ps.EndInvoke($task)
$ps.Dispose()
$rs.Dispose()
```